# Customise style of image select react native image picker

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

How do you change the colour of the react-native-image-picker choose from library screen?

I have added the following to styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
  <item name="android:actionBarStyle">#e7bd61</item>
  <item name="android:colorPrimary">#e7bd61</item>
  <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#e7bd61</item>
  <item name="android:colorAccent">#e7bd61</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">#e7bd61</item>
  <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

This code allows the Dialog to be styled however doesn't allow styling on the choose from library screen.